# How to count a number of unique rows considering that A, B row = B, A row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new in SQL therefore sorry in advance for possible mistakes, incorrect questions.

I am trying to solve the following task:

There is a table with two columns.

[image: Table]

My task is to COUNT the number of unique rows, considering that the rows which have the same information (regardless of the order) are counted as 1.

EG. row `[1] a b` and  row `[2] b a` should be counted as 1

So the result of the query should be 3

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Sorry forgot to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as least,
       (case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col3 end) as greatest,
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end),
         (case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col3 end);
```

Many databases support the `least()` and `greatest()` functions which simplify this logic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select *, count(*)
from
(
select
case when Column2<Column1 then Column2 else Column1 end as Column1, 
case when Column1>Column2 then Column1 else Column2 end as Column2
from tab
) as t
group by Column1,Column2
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd2ae25d4523c4b3f1e84ac41d017b36).

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way of doing it, but if you don't need to `group by`, here is another method:

```
select 
count(distinct case when col2<col1 then concat(col2,col1) else concat(col1,col2) end)
from your_table;
```